# php loop through xml sibling once for matching sibling then move to next

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing, simplexml

The xml siblngs are listed by dates. Each date may be listed many times due to different times in each date. Such as...

EDITED: ADDED XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theaterxml>
<theatreid>12345</theatreid>-
<filmtitle>
    <name>Movie Name 1</name>
    <shortname>MOVIENAME1</shortname>
    <rating>R</rating>
    <length>101</length>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show> 
</filmtitle>
<filmtitle>
    <name>Movie Name 2</name>
    <shortname>MOVIENAME2</shortname>
    <rating>R</rating>
    <length>101</length>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02022013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02032013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1205</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1305</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show>
    <show>
        <screen>1</screen>
        <date>02042013</date>
        <time>1605</time>
        <salelink>http://mysite.com/foo?linkToThisTimeAndDate=999</salelink>
    </show> 
</filmtitle>
```

When I use foreach to get to the date child of the main xml I get only the first date. When I use a while loop it displays every occurance of every date until there are no more dates.

What I need to do is run a while loop that displays each date once, then the next different date until there are no more. Then, inside that while loop I need another that displays each time for that date until there are no more. I need to be able to decide which date and its times are shown by using $_GET['date'] and the url of ?date=01022013.

I hope that makes sense. I'm typing this on mobile and don't have access to my PC right now to copy/paste the actual code or xml.

EDITED: AT PC NOW

that's seems to be a lot of xml, but that's only a snippet. the full xml shows 8 to 13 movies, 2 to 5 times a day, sometimes over a course of 3 weeks. it gets hefty having to be loaded each time. right now i'm using simplexml, but would much rather use xmlreader.

today the xml is 97.6KB. that's a lot to pull each time someone goes to one page, selects one of several dates, then goes to another page, etc. between this and the images, that's a lot of data to display a single page every time a page is clicked on or changed. especially on slow connections, mobile, etc.

right now i'm sorta under the gun on this project and trying to further-learn/re-learn this has put me even farther behind. personally i despise xml and would prefer that their in-house software build this in a mysql database, but this is what i have to work with. furthermore, the company who designed this could have structured it better too.

Comment: Ok! Will answer the question tomorrow. In Europe it's now 0300 .. will leave for today. see you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for something like this:

```
// create a DOM document and load your xml (as string)
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

// create a xpath selector for the document
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);

// get all show elements
$showResult = $selector->query('//show');

// dates will contain the results
$dates = array();
foreach($showResult as $show) {
    // get the date sub node 
    $dateResult = $selector->query('date', $show);
    if(count($dateResult) !== 1) {
        die('bad xml');
    }
    $date = $dateResult->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // get the time sub node 
    $timeResult = $selector->query('time', $show);
    if(count($timeResult) !== 1) {
        die('bad xml');
    }
    $time = $timeResult->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // if it is the first the time the date appears
    // we create an empty array for this index. The 
    // array will contain the timestamps
    if(!isset($dates[$date])) {
        $dates[$date] = array();
    }

    // add time to array if the same does not exists
    if(!in_array($time, $dates[$date], TRUE)) {
        $dates[$date][] = $time;
    }
}

// get all dates and times
var_dump($dates);

// get times for 02022013
var_dump($dates['02022013']);
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but after looking into xml parsing even further, i realized i needed to be using simplexml and xpath to perform this because i need to compare different sections of the xml to produce the result needed. this thread can be deleted by an admin, etc. thank you @hek2mgl for your assistance and i do regret wasting your time. please forgive me.

Comment: @JSP254 I'm using XPath in the example. With the DOM extension. the result is the same as with simplexml. Why do you need simplexml?

Comment: honestly, because i do not have anywhere near the knowledge to use DOM. i have many more sections within this page where i need to pull information from the same xml file. when i search for methods to parse the xml, all of the DOM methods are way over my head. i can understand the simplexml methods much easier. again, i do apologize!

Comment: while trying to use your example, it took me a while to figure out how to get this to load the xml file.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should told you. I expected that $xml is already loaded.

Comment: About DOMDocument and simplexml. Both extension are for the same purpose, where simple xml claims to have the 'simpler' syntax. Its up to you what you'll use. I prefer DOM as its a standard across programming languages

Comment: i understand. i truly wish i had more knowledge of other programming languages. my knowledge of this stuff has always been on an as needed basis. no formal training at all, and it takes me a while to grasp the understanding of it. the designer of the system that produces the xml file here could have made the structure a little more user friendly also. most of these things should be children of certain nodes instead of siblings. IE; one date with children nodes with the times for that date. oh well, it is what it is. thanks again!

Comment: I would say the xml looks good. You can ask me if you need help. We can also open a chat if you want.

Comment: i will keep that in mind! thank! you may someday regret that offer though! HAHA